# SwiftUI: Working with RTL language like Arabic

Tags: swift, swiftui

If you have worked with RTL language like Arabic, maybe you could give me some guides on how I can display the language correctly in swiftui.

I tried something like below but it is actually not correct as they are still left aligned.

```
 if nativeLanguage == "Arabic" {
     HStack {
         Spacer()
         Text("مرحبا هذا نص طويل ولكنه باللغة العربية فكيف يمكن عرضه بشكل صحيح")
            .font(.system(size: 16))
            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
          }
       } else {
           HStack {
             Text("Hello there")
               .font(.system(size: 16))
               .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
             Spacer()
           }
        }
```

Comment: Just put translations in corresponding Localizable.strings files and use in code `Text` with only based language (eg. `Text("Hello there")`) and that's it. You can read next for more details https://phrase.com/blog/posts/swiftui-tutorial-localization/.

Comment: @Asperi, it is not related to locale or translation file actually

Comment: Making correct localization gives run-times the information of supported languages and make a change to handle texts UI correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additionally to a comment above

```
Text("someText") // assuming this one localized correctly
    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
```